# Importance of 'supported account type' when registering an app with application permission

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I build a web app which send mails (with Microsoft Graph) but not on behalf of users. Rather think of a 'do-not-reply email' sent to users with some info. The application should have "Mail.Send" application permission on Microsoft Graph. The mail address is do-not-reply@contoso.com and this is an application mailbox (shared mailbox).

So the basic scenario is:

- User John Doe fill in a form on contoso.com website and submit it
- A mail is sent to the user to confirm the submission of the form
- The mail sender is ALWAYS do-not-reply@contoso.com and the mail receiver is (in this case) john.doe@anything.com

Given my explanations, I think of registering an application on my Azure Active Directory with "application permission" (request for admin consent) **Client Crediential Flow**. Correct ?

Also, is there any importance when choosing the *Supported account types* when registering a new application with "application permission" ? From my understanding, since the administrator consent permission from the start of the implementation, this account type choice has no impact.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You should follow [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) to get the access token. It uses "application permission" with **Client Credential Flow**.

And "supported account types" only effects where the Azure AD app can be used. It doesn't effect on which authentication flow you use. If you just want to use it in your own Azure AD tenant, just choose the first **Accounts in this organizational directory only**. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-an-application).